# How do I set a fix width to an inner div-element when using display properties

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'm looking for a property, which

1. Centers an inner div-element horizontal
2. Sets the width of that inner div-element to a fix width of 40px

I tried following to see whether it works.
I used `display:table` and `display:table-cell` because there will be more table-cells and table-rows in it. It is just an example of a non working case.

When I use display:table with a width of 100% I can center the inner div-element.
This would be the solution for (1).

My problem is point (2).
I want to have a table-cell with a width of 40px. 
At the moment the inner div expands to the 100% width of the outer div.
You can see what I mean by having a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2sK6Q/).
The border around the number should be only 40px wide.

Have you got an idea how to solve it?

```
<div style="display:table;width:100%;height:47px;border:1px solid blue;text- align:center;">  
         <div style="display:table-cell;width:40px;height:47px;border:1px solid red"> 1</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: If you're displaying tabular data, a table is perfectly legal. Don't be afraid to use them, just don't use them for layout :)

Comment: I need it for layout. and i'm afraid there is no other way to style it.

Answer (score 2):

Why not:

```
div.inner {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 40px;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately it makes no difference. And I need the display:table-cell property

Answer (score 1):

You can use this in HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">  
         <div class="inner"> 1</div> 
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.wrapper
{
   width:100%;
   height:47px;
   border:1px solid blue;
   text-align:center;
}

.inner
{  
   margin: 0 auto;
   width:40px;
   height:47px;
   border:1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that it's gonna be a table with more table-cells.

Comment: Ok, can we see a more expanded example? Maybe there are problems elsewhere :)

Answer (score 1):

If you set it to behave like a table, it will behave like a table and if there is only one column, it will have the width of the table.

So you can either add more cells to fill the whole table or get rid of the table layout and use @Summer's solution.

Comment: so there is no way to set the width of a single table-cell?

Comment: @qlib there is, but only when there are more columns and the rest make up for the remaining space.